# How do I copy files from 2 different init containers to the same path in the main container in the same Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 initcontainers each one containing a file in their home directory. I need to copy these files from these initcontainers to the same directory (/home/scripts) in my main container.

When I am trying to mount 2 emptyDir volumes with the same mountpath (/home/scripts) for both the initcontainers and the main container, the deployment does not run giving the error that the same mountpath cannot be used.

The alternate method I tried was to mount the 2 files from the initcontainers into 2 separate mountpaths on the main container and then copy the files from those mountpaths to the required directory (/home/scripts) in the main container through a script defined in the configMap definition.
But with this case, the deployment throws the error that the file is not found to be copied from the source directory which is basically the mountpath of each of the initcontainers.

If I bash into the main container manually and check, then the files can be seen in the mountpaths.

Is there something I am doing wrong or some other way that the required can be achieved ?

**Note -: The directory on the main container cannot be changed. It has to be the same.**

Comment: Can you combine the two init containers into one?  Or move this setup into the main image, maybe via an entrypoint wrapper script?  Or have just one `emptyDir` volume, that gets mounted into all three containers?

Comment: Yes, creating only one emptyDir volume and mounting it in all 3 container worked like a charm. Thanks !!